# Return the property name from a nested object literal

Tags: javascript

I have an object and I'm trying to get the name of the parent property of a method.

`var a = {b: {c: function() {return // I want "b" }}}`

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean dynamically right?

Comment: How are you calling the function? Functions don't really "know" who has a reference to them.

Comment: How do you call the function if you don't already have a reference to `a.b`? What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. When a variable object contains a reference to a function, there's no reference in the reverse direction. There can also be multiple references, e.g.

```
var a = {b: {c: function() {return // I want "b" }}}
var x = {y: {z: a.b.c}};
```

Now `a.b.c` and `x.y.z` are the same function, how would it know whether to return `b` or `y`?

Note, however, that when you call the function as

```
a.b.c()
```

it receives the *value* of `a.b` as the context in `this`. So you can do something like:

```js
var a = {
  b: {
    c: function() {
      console.log(this.d);
    },
    d: 1
  }
};

var x = {
  y: {
    z: a.b.c,
    d: 10
  }
};

a.b.c();
x.y.z();
```

This still doesn't help you get the property name `b`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a function iterating the object that contains the function *but we have to know the main object* (in this case **a**).

To call that function, since we don't know **b**, we have to iterate the properties of **a** and the nested objects to find it.

```js
var a = {b: {c: function() {for(p in a)console.log(p) }}}

for(p in a){
    for(p2 in a[p]){
        a[p][p2]();
    }
}
```

I'm probably forcing the rules because you didn't say anything about the main object (a), but the idea here is to start from the beginning and move along to reach the goal.